# cfspreadsheet update cell directly

Tags: coldfusion, cfspreadsheet

Can `cfspreadsheet` (or anything else using cold fusion) be used to update just a few cells in an existing xlsx spreadsheet?
I have updated entire sheets in the past - using an object - but the sheet in question is so massive and messy - I only want to be able to edit a few of the cells - without have to read and validate ALL the columns.
basically the ability to use `SpreadsheetSetCellValue` directly on the spreadsheet as opposed to working only on the spreadsheet object that must be read in and updated/written back as an entire sheet.

Comment: The short answer is "no".  To modify a single cell in a spreadsheet, CF must load the whole workbook into memory first. No way to avoid that unless you understand the xlsx format and know how to manipulate the internal xml files, which is NOT trivial. Don't know what you mean by validation. Using SpreadsheetSetCellValue and writing back to disk doesn't require any validation, ordinarily.

Comment: @Ageax True, but like you said, Once CF loads the entire workbook into memory, it's easy enough to manipulate individual cells and then overwrite the existing xlsx file.  Here's a simple example in a blog post by Ben Forta http://forta.com/blog/index.cfm/2009/6/18/Working-With-Spreadsheets-In-ColdFusion

Comment: @user9263373 - Agreed. From the few details in the post it wasn't clear if they were just misunderstanding how to use it. The OP suggests there is something undesirable about loading the whole thing, but doesn't provide much detail. That's why I asked about what they meant by "without have to read and *validate ALL the columns.*".

Comment: "Don't know what you mean by validation." => if there are 250 columns and I am interested in only 15 of them, I need to 'validate' that all 250 columns are correct before replacing the sheet I am updating...

Comment: No need to "validate" anything, unless that is specific to your application.  Like @user9263373 said, just open the workbook, activate a sheet, update the cell(s) you want and write it to disk - using [spreadsheet functions](https://cfdocs.org/spreadsheet%2Dfunctions), NOT cfspreadsheet.

Comment: Yes @Ageax is correct.  Just update the cells you need to and everything else will remain as is.  In other words the if the untouched cells were already valid, then they will remain so after updating/saving the worksheet.  It's as simple as trying it, what have you got to lose :)